# What is a common sound frequency -> human-perceived information-density diagram?

Tags: audio, mp3, signal-processing, fft

Different sound frequencies are perceived differently well by a human. E.g., the frequency which can be heard at all are from 20 Hz to 20 kHz; see [Hearing range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range).

Different frequency also are perceived with different sensitivity as shown by [equal-loudness contours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour); see also [Loudness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness). This is relevant when measuring the human-perceived loudness, e.g. see [ReplayGain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReplayGain).

However, I would guess that the diagram must not necessarily be the same for human-perceived information-density (if you can call it that way). E.g. there might be frequencies which are perceived as loud but where the perceived information density is not that high. I'm not sure if that is the case. Is it? Or is it basically the same? Maybe my understanding of it is also too naive.

From my naive understanding how MP3 works (and other lossy audio encodings) is that it stores more information for the frequencies which are more important and less for the ones which are less important. "More important" means that the human-perceived information-density is higher.

(Meta: Maybe StackOverflow is not the best SE site to ask this. What would be a better one?)

Comment: The "information content" is not related to just a single isolated factor or parameter, such a frequency band.

Comment: One important factor to consider is that the bandwidth of the auditory filters in the cochlea is roughly proportional to frequency (i.e. constant Q). The minimum frequency difference that we can discriminate is therefore higher at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

Psychoacoustically perceived "information density" is hard to define. However, the just-differentiable pitch contour (e.g., the [Mel scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale)) comes close. It is not based upon perceived loudness with regard to pitch/frequency but the human auditory system's ability to perceive subjectively different pitches / notice the smallest change in pitch across the frequency spectrum. If "information" is pitch / fundamental frequency of an auditory event, then the Mel scale describes "information density" per frequency.

In that case, you are right, because the Mel scale is independent of loudness, though correlated for some of the frequency spectrum. There are frequencies which are perceived as loud but where this perceived "information density" is not that high, as you say.

However, perceived loudness itself is information, and for that and other psychoacoustic factors which impact successful transfer of information into the human auditory system, you may want to look into [Critical Bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_bands) and especially [Auditory Masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking).